# How to prove that tr(A) = tr(B) given that B is similar to A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

If A and B are similar, how does one prove that `tr(A) = tr(B)`

Comment: If they are similar they have the same characteristic polynomials i.e. same eigenvalues

Comment: You probably know that $\text{tr}(ABC)=\text{tr}(CAB)$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** show that $\operatorname{tr}(CD) = \operatorname{tr}(DC)$

Comment: You might want to use different variables. It might confuse OP.

Comment: I get what the hint means, though don't get how it helps (struggling through linear algebra).

Comment: @sinθ Since $tr(CD) = tr(DC)$, what happens if you have $tr(SCS^{-1})$? (Try moving one of the $S$ or $S^{-1}$ around in the trace formula.)

Answer (score 1):

if $A$ and $B$ are similar, then $p(\lambda) = \det(A- \lambda I) = \det(B- \lambda I)$. therefore $$\operatorname{trace}(A) = \operatorname{trace}(B) = \text{coefficient  of } \lambda^{n-1} \text{ in } p(\lambda) $$